# Round corners for BottomSheet expanded?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, material-ui

Out of curiosity, what needs to be done that the damn bottom sheet actually keeps its rounded corners in expanded state?

Im struggling the whole day with that issue, i have a bottomsheet defined in XML, material design 1.9 and it still flattens them. Are there any files that require a replacement?

Depends...

```
dependencies {

    implementation project(':unityLibrary')
    implementation fileTree(dir: project(':unityLibrary').getProjectDir().toString() + ('\\libs'), include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.0")    // Kotlin

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

```
            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/standard_bottom_sheet"
                    style="@style/Widget.Material3.BetterBottomSheet"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:behavior_hideable="false"
                    app:behavior_peekHeight="32dp"
                    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
...
```

```
<style name="Widget.Material3.BetterBottomSheet" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomSheet">
        <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/m3_bottom_sheet_elevation</item>
        <item name="marginLeftSystemWindowInsets">true</item>
        <item name="marginRightSystemWindowInsets">true</item>
        <item name="paddingBottomSystemWindowInsets">true</item>
        <item name="paddingTopSystemWindowInsets">true</item>
        <item name="paddingLeftSystemWindowInsets">false</item>
        <item name="paddingRightSystemWindowInsets">false</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearance">@macro/m3_comp_sheet_bottom_docked_container_shape</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Material3.Corner.Top</item>
        <item name="shouldRemoveExpandedCorners">false</item>  // True also does not work
        <item name="backgroundTint">@macro/m3_comp_sheet_bottom_docked_container_color</item>
    </style>
```

What am i doing wrong here? Is there a way to make a BottomSheet keep its round corners once expanded?

Answer (score 1):

The bottom sheet can not have bottom corners. This was a big debate on the developers side. The rounded corners indicated that there was scrollable text. So they only allow for the top to be rounded.

See this: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/437#issuecomment-536668983

So we are forever stuck with only top round corners unless they decide to let us override the method.

Comment: The top rounded corners, those are which i want to stay round once expanded. So in this case... that should be possible right? But how?

Comment: Override the layoutappearence

Comment: Create the custom rounded corners xml.. then override Appearance layout and use the custom xml instead

Comment: I don't have the exact code with me because I am in waiting room while wife has surgery so I won't be able to get you the code exactly what I do until tomorrow

Comment: fun getTheme() = R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme  .....is one way you can do it

Comment: This worked for me when using BottomSheetDialogFragment:

public class CustomDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme);
  }
  
  ...
}

Comment: Hope that gives you some ideas